# How to submit form with Javascript or to the next page

Tags: javascript, forms

I have created a form and it seems to validate well.

I am having trouble submitting the page because of the onclick button. This has now confused me slightly and would like to place the command in the javascript.

How do I write it in the javascript?

Here is the [demo of the form](http://jsfiddle.net/c2webdev/k4KmL/2/)

```
<script language="javascript">
  function button_actions(){

    if (!document.my_form.referrers_name.value){
      alert('You need to supply your Referrers name.');
      document.my_form.referrers_name.focus();
      return false;
    }

    if (!document.my_form.referrers_organisation.value){
      alert('You need to supply your Referrers organisation.');
      document.my_form.referrers_organisation.focus();
      return false;
    }

    if (!document.my_form.referrers_email_address.value){
      alert('You need to supply your Referrers email address.');
      document.my_form.referrers_email_address.focus();
      return false;
    }

    if (!document.my_form.referrers_phone_number.value){
      alert('You need to supply your Referrers phone number.');
      document.my_form.referrers_phone_number.focus();
      return false;
    }


    if (!document.my_form.referral_document.value){
      alert('You need to supply your Referral Document.');
      document.my_form.referral_document.focus();
      return false;
    }

    if (!document.my_form.name_of_contact.value){
      alert('You need to supply a Name of contact.');
      document.my_form.name_of_contact.focus();
      return false;
    }

    if (!document.my_form.email_of_contact.value){
      alert('You need to supply an Email of contact.');
      document.my_form.email_of_contact.focus();
      return false;
    }


    if (!document.my_form.phone_of_contact.value){
      alert('You need to supply a Phone number of contact.');
      document.my_form.phone_of_contact.focus();
      return false;
    }

    if (!document.my_form.details.value){
      alert('You need to supply further details.');
      document.my_form.details.focus();
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having the function fire on the button using `onclick`, try firing it on the form using `onsubmit`.

```
<form name="my_form" method="post" action="assign any page to this" onsubmit="return button_actions();">
```

and then just use a simple submit button to trigger the `onsubmit`:

```
<input type="submit">
```

The form will now submit when it passes validation.

Comment: I followed what you said but it cancelled out the validations.